# Matlab code for general multinomial formula

Tags: statistics, static-analysis, usage-statistics, multinomial

I would like to know if there is Matlab code that can solve the multinomial formula. I can write a code for finite number of terms in the multinomial formula, for example, `(x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3})^4`.
But for general case, I found it is not easy, i.e.  `(x_{1}+x_{2}+ .... +x_{m})^n`

[image]

Comment: What do you want to solve it for? Do you just want to compute the [multinomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)?

Comment: It is not just the multinomial coefficient, I have a case when I need to solve and analyse each of the components inside the multinomial. So, I am looking for a code that can solve a general multinomial problem.
for example, I may need to solve the integral that involve this multinomial (x1+x2+...+x6)^7 
Therefore, I need to expand the multinomial so that I can solve it.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by solve? You can only solve an equation, not an expression! You can't *solve* `(x1 + x2 + ... + x6)^7`...

Comment: Your question is very unclear!

Comment: I think my question is very simple to understand;
Can you write a matlab code that can solve the multinomial?

Comment: Once again: There is no *solving the multinomial*. What would be your answer if I asked: *How do I solve `(x_1 + x_2)^2`?*

Comment: for that case it is very simple, it is just a binomial and you have only one sum, in fact you can say x1, x2, ... xn are constants, they can take any real value. therefore the matlab code for your case can be as the following;
x1=4;
x2=8;
K=2;
sum=0;
for i=0:K
fact=factorial(K)/(factorial(i)*factorial(K-i));
sum=sum+(fact*x1^(i)*x2^(K-i));
end
result=sum;
check=(x1+x2)^K;

Comment: Why don't you just use your `check` variable as `result = (x1 + x2)^K`? This will have the same result as your for-loop. There is no need in using the loop!

Comment: In fact it is not always x1 and x2 known
look at this

syms x1 x2
K=2;
sum=0;
for i=0:K
fact=factorial(K)/(factorial(i)*factorial(K-i));
sum=sum+(fact*x1^(i)*x2^(K-i));
end
result=sum;

Comment: I don't have the symbolic toolbox installed, so I can't use this. I still think with the symbolic toolbox you should be able to use: `(x1+x2)^2`
Also your question doesn't state anything about symbolics!

Comment: OK, Thanks.
simply, can you write a Matlab code for general case? what I did is for 2 term only (i.e. binomial), can you write a code for multinomial? Yes or NO?

Comment: I don't see a reason to do so, as `(x1 + x2 + ... + xm)^n` will yield the same result. Doesn't `m = 3; n=4; X = sym('x',m); symsum(X(i),1,m)^n` work?

Comment: after this all discussion you don't want to say I can't write the code, instead you say I don't see a reason ....

Comment: Because you still have not made clear what you actually want!
Does my code above not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question as: *Using the symbolic toolbox, how do I expand the multinomial*

```
(x_{1} + x_{2} + .... + x_{m})^n
```

*to be able to see all its coefficients?*

And my answer for you is:

```
m = 2; n = 3;
X = sym('x', [1,m]);
expand(sum(X)^n)
```

Which will yield:

```
>> x1^3 + 3*x1^2*x2 + 3*x1*x2^2 + x2^3
```